# Newline formatting is not supported in contentDescription property of CSSearchableItemAttributeSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, corespotlight

I am having a `CSSearchableItem` with `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet`,

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet* attributes = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc]initWithItemContentType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeContact];
attributes.keywords = @[keywords];
attributes.title = @"Contact Details";
attributes.displayName = @"Ram Gandhi";
attributes.emailAddresses = @[email];
attributes.phoneNumbers = @[phoneNumber];
attributes.contentDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", phoneNumber, email];
attributes.supportsPhoneCall = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
attributes.supportsNavigation = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
attributes.thumbnailData = [self getThumbnailData:contactID];
```

Everything is working fine but the newline in `contentDescription` is not working as expected though it is not displayed in the UI.

Also I am not sure about the purpose of using `kUTTypeContact` here as `kUTTypeContent` does the job. As far as I searched, there is no detailed documentation about how to use `kUTTypeContact` in Spotlight search.

Is there any other property that I can use inorder to show the email and phone number in separate lines?

Comment: It was before, seems to have stopped working in iOS10. Have you had any luck resolving this?

Comment: Nope.. As for now, we have to use appropriate ItemContentType and properties that suit our need, so that it will be rendered in their default UI.

Comment: Do we have any docs on how each ItemContentType renders to? Also any one of them allow multi line description?

Comment: I used kUTTypeMP3 and tried some props in 'Describing Music' here,
https://developer.apple.com/reference/corespotlight/cssearchableitemattributeset

Comment: I used musicalGenre and the artist key to get a second line. Any way to get a third line? I have most of the keys but couldn't

Comment: Looks like you could have a third line when describing a movie, look at the image
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/Activities.html

Comment: has anyone filed a radar for this (presumed) bug?

Answer (score 0):

it might be very late answer for you but it can help other. now , while using swift 4 we can add 2 lines "contentDescription" as below ,

```
var contentDescription = ""
var arrDescription = ["email","phone"]
for (index,strDesc) in arrDescription.enumerated(){
    if index == 0{
        contentDescription = strDesc
    }else{
        contentDescription += """

        \(strDesc)
        """
    }
}
```

I also have try to add more then two strings, but it display only upto two lines , then it will show ... at the end of second line.

**Note: - check that "blank line", before "(strDesc)", it is not by mistake, it must be there to display newline.**